# why driven methods use the fields in the basic class

Tags: java

I have class `A`:

```
public class A extends Top{    
    int i=88;
}
```

and `Top`:

```
public class Top {

    int i = 99;

    public void tt() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

why when I call tt():

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        a.tt();

    }

}
```

it shows 99 as the result not 88? BUT at the `toString` method in Object class:

```
 public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

`getClass` gets the driven class, not the Object class?

Comment: Fields exist in each class level separately. This tt prints i from base class, but getClass is called on the specific object at runtime - that is the essence of polymorphism.

Comment: @GhostCat please add some more information and then post it as the answer, thanks

Comment: You should look more closely on the feedback you get. Your question is on hold, because there is another question that explains all of it. Thus even if I would be willing to do your homework, I can't answer a on hold question. Study the duplicated question!

Comment: @GhostCat homework !!! I'm old enough not to have any homework left !!! just wanted to give you some credit for the answer,

Comment: Sorry, then i misread your comment. There are far too many newbies that don't understand that DUP question thing. They want a specific explanation just for their answer. So, as said sorry. And no need for special credit here. Probably we meet again and I can give a real answer to another question then...